# In Python3 with nltk how can you return true if a certain word is a verb,noun.etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I need for my function to return true if the first word in an input is a verb.
I tried this but it did not work(aka didn't return anything despite it being a verb), can someone show me an example of what im doing wrong. Also an example of what the correct way to do this is, Thank you!

```
def All():
    what_person_said = input()
    what_person_said_wt = nltk.word_tokenize(what_person_said)
    result = nltk.pos_tag(what_person_said_wt[0])
    if result == 'VB':
        print ("First word is a verb")
        return True
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: should of returned true but didn't

Comment: Try printing result, it'll help debug it

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this list of codes is up to date, but [this](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) is the source for the VERB_CODES in the code below.

```
import nltk

# A verb could be categorized to any of the following codes
VERB_CODES = {
    'VB',  # Verb, base form
    'VBD',  # Verb, past tense
    'VBG',  # Verb, gerund or present participle
    'VBN',  # Verb, past participle
    'VBP',  # Verb, non-3rd person singular present
    'VBZ',  # Verb, 3rd person singular present
}

def All():
    print ("Please provide a sentence:")
    user_provided_input = input()

    # TEST SENTENCE (instead of requiring user input)
    # user_provided_input = "Running is fun."

    print ("The user provided: {}".format(user_provided_input))

    # tokenize the sentence
    user_provided_input_token = nltk.word_tokenize(user_provided_input)
    print ("The user input token: {}".format(user_provided_input_token))

    # [tag][2] the tokens
    result = nltk.pos_tag(user_provided_input_token)
    print ("Result: {}".format(result))

    # only look at the first word
    first_word_result = result[0]
    print ("First word result: {}".format(first_word_result))

    # get the first word's corresponding code (or tag?)
    first_word_code = first_word_result[1]
    print ("First word code: {}".format(first_word_code))

    # check to see if the first word's code is contained in VERB_CODES
    if first_word_code in VERB_CODES:
        print ("First word is a verb")
        return True
    else:
        print("First word is not a verb")
        return False

def main():
    All()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
Please provide a sentence:
Runnning is fun.
The user provided: Runnning is fun.
The user input token: ['Runnning', 'is', 'fun', '.']
Result: [('Runnning', 'VBG'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('fun', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
First word result: ('Runnning', 'VBG')
First word code: VBG
First word is a verb
```

Take a look at the comments in the code and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really awesome i hope it works i'll go test it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def All():
    what_person_said = input()
    what_person_said_wt = nltk.word_tokenize(what_person_said)

    result = str(nltk.pos_tag(what_person_said_wt[0]))
    print(result)
    if len(result.split(',')[1].split("VB"))>0:
        print ("First word is a verb")
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
nltk.word_tokenize(word)
```

(Of course you need import nltk

```
from nltk.corpus import word_tokenize
```

)

```
nltk.pos_tag()
```

Returns 'VB' or 'VBP' etc.